# SwiftUI Spacer not working - The element isn't pushed to the end of the row

Tags: swiftui

I have a cell row which contains the following:

```
HStack {
    Text(self.category.name.capitalizingFirstLetter())
        .font(.body)
        .fontWeight(.light)
    Spacer()
        .background(Color.red)
    if category.id == selectedCategoryID {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.pink)
            .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

I am trying to have the Circle appear on the right side of the row and this is why I used the Spacer.
This is how it actually looks like:

[image]

I added the background color for the circle and the spacer only for better visual of the situation.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the `Circle` view is taking up the entirety of the horizontal *and* vertical space, even though what is actually rendered as the circle is only shown in a small part (you can visualize this more clearly by adding a `.border(Color.green)` to the `Circle` view).

To fix this, you can use `aspectRatio` to make sure that the actual frame of the circle view stays a square (ie an aspect ratio of `1.0`)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("test")
                .font(.body)
                .fontWeight(.light)
            Spacer()
            Circle()
                       .foregroundColor(.pink)
                       .background(Color.yellow)
                       .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
}
```

It isn't immediately clear to me where you want the `yellow` background -- if you want it still taking up as much horizontal space as possible (but not under the text), you could use an additional `HStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("test")
                .font(.body)
                .fontWeight(.light)
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Circle()
                  .foregroundColor(.pink)
                  .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you wanted this

[image: demo]

```
    Circle()
        .foregroundColor(.pink)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)    // << here !!
        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false) // << here !!
```